# PF, load balanced gateways, and Squid

Tags: firewall, load-balancing, freebsd, bsd, squid

So I have a FreeBSD router running PF and Squid, and it has three network interfaces: two connected to upstream providers (`em0` and `em1` respectively), and one for LAN (`re0`) that we serve. There is some load balancing configured with PF. Basically, it routes all traffic to ports `1-1024` through one interface (`em0`) and everything else through the other (`em1`).

Now, I have a Squid proxy also running on the box that transparently redirects any HTTP request from LAN to port `3128` in `127.0.0.1`. Since Squid redirects this request to HTTP outside, it should follow the load balancing rule through `em0`, no? The problem is, when we tested it out (by browsing from a computer in the LAN to http://whatismyip.com, it reports the external IP of the `em1` interface! When we turn Squid off, the external IP of `em0` is reported, as expected.

How do I make Squid behave with the load balancing rule that we have set up?

Here's the related settings in `/etc/pf.conf` that I have:

```
ext_if1="em1"   # DSL
ext_if2="em0"   # T1
int_if="re0"

ext_gw1="x.x.x.1"
ext_gw2="y.y.y.1"

int_addr="10.0.0.1"
int_net="10.0.0.0/16"

dsl_ports = "1024:65535"
t1_ports = "1:1023"

...

squid=3128
rdr on $int_if inet proto tcp from $int_net \
        to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port $squid
pass in quick on $int_if route-to lo0 inet proto tcp \
        from $int_net to 127.0.0.1 port $squid keep state

...

# load balancing
pass in on $int_if route-to ($ext_if1 $ext_gw1) \
        proto tcp from $int_net to any port $dsl_ports keep state
pass in on $int_if route-to ($ext_if1 $ext_gw1) \
        proto udp from $int_net to any port $dsl_ports

pass in on $int_if route-to ($ext_if2 $ext_gw2) \
        proto tcp from $int_net to any port $t1_ports keep state
pass in on $int_if route-to ($ext_if2 $ext_gw2) \
        proto udp from $int_net to any port $t1_ports

pass out on $ext_if1 route-to ($ext_if2 $ext_gw2) from $ext_if2 to any
pass out on $ext_if2 route-to ($ext_if1 $ext_gw1) from $ext_if1 to any
```

I have tried appending the following rule, but it did nothing:

```
pass in on $int_if route-to ($ext_if2 $ext_gw2) \
        proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 to any port $t1_ports keep state
```

Thanks!

Comment: After scouring through archives on the 'net, the closest thing I could find was this [unsolved discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/pf@benzedrine.cx/msg05744.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all outgoing squid requests to go to a specific IP address on a specific interface, you should be able to use the "tcp_outgoing_address" option in squid.conf to specify an IP address on em0.